# Pandas map() function with datetime64 type as mapping value

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to add a new column `Temperature` to my dataframe `data`, from the dict `weather`. Using the `map()` function to match up the dates in `data` with the dates in `weather`, both are `datetime64` format.

```
import pandas as pd

# Import first dataset and convert dates to datetime64
filename = 'Process Data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data['trans_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(data.trans_date1)

# Import second dataset and convert dates to datetime64
filenameWeather = '2014-2018 Weather Data.csv'
dataWeather = pd.read_csv(filenameWeather, parse_dates=True)
dataWeather['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataWeather.Date_Time)


# Create new dataframe to hold only the date and temp 
weather = dataWeather[[('Date_Time'), 'Mean_Temp_?C']].copy()

# Convert this to a dict
weather = weather.to_dict('split')

# map weather data to main dataset
data['Temperature'] = data['trans_date1'].map(weather)
```

This will not produce an error, but will not copy over any of the temperatures, they are all `NaN`. I have also tried using different options for converting the dataframe to dict (series, split, index, list, but records produces an error).

I have checked my dates and temperatures, and the data does exist, so it should have found something to map for a particular date.

I have also tried to convert the dates to strings before mapping, this also does not result in an error, but it also only outputs `NaN` for everything in `Temperature`.

Comment: Did you debug this? Please check after every operation that your result is correct and add results of debugging to this post.

Comment: try with index id to dict. it seems to me problem is with key
example:-
 df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict('list')

Comment: @Cezary.Sz I am fairly new to programming, so my method of debugging is just a ton of print statements.

Comment: @Mr.J This worked for me for the most part, but the data was then appearing as an Object when i printed the dtype, and when i printed the data it was all coming out in square brackets, ex. '[32.0]'. When i tried to do any sort of conversion, I consistently got the error 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
weather = weather.to_dict('split')
```

produces a dictionary with structure

```
{'columns': [...],
 'data': [...],
 'index': [...] }
```

however if you want to use map with a dictonary you should have a dictonary with structure

```
{'match_value_1': 2,
 'match_value_2': 3,
  etc. }
```

Assuming you do not want to change the kind of dictionary representation in the beginning, then you can either later transform your dict to fit the approach above:

```
data['Temperature'] = data['trans_date1'].map(dict(weather['data']))
```

Or you rebuild a dataframe from the dictionary and merge them:

```
weather = pandas.DataFrame(temps['data'], columns=['Date_Time', 'Mean_Temp_?C'])
df1 = df1.merge(weather, how='inner', left_on='trans_date1', right_on='Date_Time')
```

It depends on your logic whatever kind of merge you want to perform. Please elaborate more on this, if you need further help.

Comment: Your first suggestion using 'zip' worked for me, could you explain what the  'list(zip(*weather['data']))' and the 'dict(zip(weather[0], weather[1]))' chunks are actually doing?

Comment: Oh, I updated my answer. The main part was about creating the dictionary in order to map your dates to degrees.